# Why am I getting "cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener" error when I try to connect to oracle database from vscode?

Tags: oracle

I have a script I wrote to connect to my local oracle database. It worked perfectly before now. I was able to connect and populate the database with data from vscode. After I formatted my machine and reinstalled oracle database and instance client. I couldn't connect again, whenever I try, I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\ChiNedu\Documents\python\Oracle\oracle.py", line 10, in <module>
  cnx = cx_Oracle.connect(conStr)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
PS C:\Users\ChiNedu\Documents\python\Oracle>
```

when I type `lsnrctl stat` in command prompt, I get this

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 09-FEB-2023 17:33:46

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DESKTOP-QPAJR53)(PORT=1521)))
 TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
   TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
    64-bit Windows Error: 1001: Unknown error
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
 TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
   TNS-00511: No listener
    64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

I tried to change the HOST NAME but can't find the %ORACLE_HOME%/network/admin directory from my machine services. Please help me get this fixed. Thanks.

Comment: If files in %ORACLE_HOME% are missing, you'll need to recreate them or restore them from backup. Content there will be specific to your installation, so there isn't much we can add here. Also, this is really an administration question for dba.stackexchange.com, not a software development question.

Comment: Did you change your PC name? It doesn't seem to be able to resolve `DESKTOP-QPAJR53` - I guess you copied the listener config from the old build, but it now doesn't match how your PC is configured?

Comment: @pmdba Thanks for your response. I guess I'll have to ask my question on stackexchange then. But just incase, do you mind educating me on how to restore files in %ORACLE_HOME% from backup?

Comment: @AlexPoole I appreciate your response. Yes after the full format I changed my pc name. Any idea how to change the listener config to my current pc name?

Comment: You can use netca or [Oracle Network Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netag/glossary.html#GUID-BC9AE21D-FC67-469B-95CA-51952BFF05AB) to configure the listener. But you can also just edit the `listener.ora`. I'm not sure why you wouldn't be able to find that on your PC - you would have picked your Oracle Home during installation, and can `echo %ORACLE_HOME%` in a command prompt.